# FD_SETSIZE versus calculated value

Tags: c, sockets, select-function

In a server/client setup I have a server connecting with clients on a handful (at the moment 4) of different sockets. At the moment I use select with a calculated set_size, but what are the upper limit, before it is worthwhile to use FD_SETSIZE instead?

Below are some code examples to illustrate the point. First building the set:

```
FD_ZERO(&set);
FD_SET(socket1, &set);
FD_SET(socket2, &set);
FD_SET(socket3, &set);
FD_SET(socket4, &set);
```

Here is how the set_size is calculated:

```
set_size = MAX(socket1, socket2);
set_size = MAX(set_size, socket 3);
set_size = MAX(set_size, socket4);
set_size += 1;
```

And the usage:

```
while ((cnt = select(set_size, &set, NULL, NULL, &t)) != -1 || errno == EINTR) {
    if (cnt > 0)
        // Do different stuff depending what socket is active
    else
        // Keep everything alive and add the sockets to the set again
}
```

Recently I had to add a two new sockets and I might need to add more in the future. When would you use FD_SETSIZE as opposed to the calculated set_size?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have never worried about this because it seems like it would make a very small difference compared to the performance penalty for using `select()` in the first place.

Having said that, I think it's always worth calculating the correct value, because it's not very expensive to calculate: if you keep the current `set_size` in a local variable as you propose, it's **O(1)** with a very low constant each time you add an fd (namely, a compare and possibly an update). Removing an fd is also **O(1)** except it it's the last one in the list (in which case it's **O(`set_size`)** but usually better). On the other hand, NOT calculating the `set_size` means that the kernel has to traverse all `FD_SETSIZE` entries every single time you call `select`. Since `set_size` is probably quite a bit smaller than `FD_SETSIZE`, it pays to supply the smaller value. Even if `set_size` is close to `FD_SETSIZE`, calculating `set_size` is so cheap that it's probably almost always still worth it.

Of course if you're worried about performance to this extent, you need to be looking at `poll()` instead of `select()`. Better yet, you need to be looking at `epoll` and `kqueue`, except that's not portable since those functions are only available on Linux and FreeBSD (including MacOS) respectively.

Comment: Thank you. Really good explanation. At the moment I don't worry too much about the performance, but as the use of the software increase I might need to look into performance improvements. With that in mind, it's nice to know where to start :)